# Easy way to visualize processing steps taken in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I am working very often on preprocessing data with QGIS (and Python), and the tasks are never routine tasks. So even though sometimes there is overlap, the tools I use are always varying. Therefore I don't need the model builder. However, what I would really like is to be able to make a visualisation of the steps taken. I think at a tool with which you can create graphs with edges and nodes, e.g. like mermaid or draw.io, but it would be nice, if something like it would be easier and integrated in QGIS.

Is there a tool in QGIS just for visualizing the processing steps?

I would also be open for suggestions to visualize processing steps without QGIS.

Comment: What would be an example of your desired output?

Comment: http://www.diagrams.net/ the project is also at github https://github.com/jgraph icensed under the Apache v2.

Comment: @Xeppit I just edited my question and realized diagrams.net is draw.io. This tool I also use, and it is nice for creating a good-looking graph when you have a bit more time. But a simple graph doesnt look too nice. I hope for some tool where it is easy to create a graph and looks appealing.

Comment: Are you looking for something along the lines of a profiling call graph like this one: [gprof2dot](https://github.com/jrfonseca/gprof2dot?tab=readme-ov-file)?

Answer (score 0):

No, apart from the graphical model builder there is nothing graphical/visual in QGIS in relation to processing steps.